# vb.net SerialPort writing and receiving

Tags: vb.net

I have an issue with reading the results of a serialport communication.
If have multiple functions, which are executing different commands on my device and also receiving and process the sent results on slightly different ways.

If i call the functions all at once, its not working 100% reliable. If i call only one of these functions, all of them working perfectly. Im assuming, thinks going a little to fast for the slow serialPort communication, so some functions dont get propper results when calling all "at once"

**Code which calls 3 functions (Error on different Positions: "Index out of (array) range" or "CRC incorrect")**

```
Private Sub btn_initialize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_initialize.Click

    Dim actual_mw As Double
    Dim attenuated As Integer

    'open (virtual)COMport
    If rfid.init_serialport(cb_com.SelectedItem.ToString) = True Then
        flp_data.Visible = True

        lbl_snr_data.Text = rfid.get_serial_number()

        lbl_type_data.Text = rfid.get_reader_type

        Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(rfid.get_attennuation, "\d+")
        attenuated = collection(1).Value
        If attenuated = 0 Then
            lbl_leistung_data.Text = "100mW / 100mW"
        Else
            actual_mw = 100 - (10 ^ (attenuated / 10))
            lbl_leistung_data.Text = Math.Round(actual_mw, 2) & "mW / 100mW"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Error! COM-Schnittstelle konnte nicht initialisiert werden!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If

End Sub
```

**Intialize and Dispose SerialPort**

```
Public Class RFE
    Private RF_CHECKSUM As Byte
    Private device_output() As Byte
    Private data() As Byte
    Private device_input() As Byte
    Private sp As SerialPort

    Public Function init_serialport(portName As String) As Boolean

        Try

            sp = New SerialPort

            sp.PortName = portName
            sp.BaudRate = 9600
            sp.Parity = Parity.None
            sp.DataBits = 8
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One
            sp.Handshake = Handshake.None
            sp.ReadTimeout = 500
            sp.WriteTimeout = 500

            sp.Open()

            If sp.IsOpen Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Function
    Public Function disp_serialport()

        Try

            sp.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Function
```

**Functions**

```
Public Function get_serial_number() As String

        Try

            Dim serial_number As String


            ReDim data(8)
            data(0) = RF_START_BYTE0
            data(1) = RF_START_BYTE1
            data(2) = RF_START_BYTE2
            data(3) = RF_COMMAND_START_BYTE
            data(4) = RF_READER_COMMON
            data(5) = RF_GET_SERIAL_NUMBER
            data(6) = RF_LENGTH_START_BYTE
            data(7) = &H0
            data(8) = RF_CHECKSUM_START_BYTE

            RF_CHECKSUM = Hex(calc_xor(data, 1))


            device_input = data
            Array.Resize(device_input, data.Length + 1)
            device_input(9) = "&H" & RF_CHECKSUM

            sp.Write(device_input, 0, device_input.Length)

            ReDim device_output(sp.BytesToRead)

            sp.Read(device_output, 0, device_output.Length - 1)


            If calc_xor(device_output, 3) <> device_output(14) Then
                MsgBox("CRC incorrect!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
                Form1.Close()
            End If


            serial_number = Hex(device_output(9)).PadLeft(2, "0") & "-" & Hex(device_output(10)).PadLeft(2, "0") & "-" & Hex(device_output(11)).PadLeft(2, "0") & "-" _
                & Hex(device_output(12)).PadLeft(2, "0")



            device_output = Nothing
            data = Nothing
            RF_CHECKSUM = Nothing
            sp.DiscardInBuffer()
            sp.DiscardOutBuffer()

            Return serial_number

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Function
```

The other functions are structure-vise the same, only the sent bytes and the processing of the result is slightly different.

As I said, im assueming the problem is the transaction of the signals (possibly in both directions) so the SerialPort and/or Device cant handle things fast enough.

**What do I have to do so that the communication runs reliably/sequentially?**

Maybe DataReceivedHandler could fix the Problem? But for every function I call, the processing of the result is different, how do I implement this in the DataReceivedHandler then (if the Handler could fix the Problem)?

Thank you all!

Comment: Ignoring the return value of Read() is *always* a bug.  The only guarantee you have is that it will be larger than 0, you do *not* get the guarantee that you "read all bytes".  Your code must know when a full response was received.  ReadTo() can be a good alternative, hard to guess since you did not describe the data.  You made the problem considerably worse by calling DiscardInBuffer(), high odds that it accidentally throws away bytes you need to still read.

Comment: You have to read the output from DataReceived event. See this [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, but how do i manage this with multiple functions?
The DataReceivedHandler works asynchron. So my main Problem is this:

I have 3 functions which perform communication over the serial port, all 3 functions are fired on a button click. I think i have to dothis:

**-start first function, wait until communication is completed then
-start second function, wait until communication is completed then
-start third function**

But dont know how to do this